# How to change state of multiple React children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Down below is `<SidebarOption />` and `<SideBarConatiners />` these are both items that have a state called `open` to highlight them whenever they have been clicked and they are inside the `<SidebarItemList />`

```
       <SideBarItemList>
        <SidebarOption id="1" name="Startsida: Fjärrvärmenät" />
        <SidebarOption id="2" name="Startsida: Användare" />
        <SideBarContainers id="3" name="Allmänt" 
        options={[
            "Senaste uppdaterad", "Visa Pluginmoduler", "Öppna Arkivet", "Personliga inställningar", 
            "Regionala inställningar", "Om Driftportalen"
            ]}/>
        <SideBarContainers id="4" name="Planering" notPressAble={[0, 6, 11]}
        options={[
            "Aktiviteter:", "+ Ny Aktivitet", "Visa Alla Öppna", "Visa Försenat", "Visa Alla Stängda", "Visa Alla Kategoriserat",
            "Att göra:", "+ Ny Att göra", "Visa Alla Öppna", "Visa Alla Stängda", "Visa Alla Kategoriserat", 
            "Personal planering:", "+ Ny post", "Visa Alla enkel"
        ]} />
        </SideBarItemList>
```

Down below is the `<SideBarItemList />` class, i want to change the open value of the items soo that if one item is higlighted and another item is pressed i want all the other items to set the state `open` to `false` so that only one item state `open` can be set to `true` the problem is that the items state `open` does not seem to be extensible what can i do about this?

my error: Cannot add property open, object is not extensible

```
import { Component } from "react";

class SideBarItemList extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            sidebarItems: null
        };
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
        return{
            sidebarItems: props.children
        };
    }

    handleItems = () => {
        let openNumber = null;
        for(let x = 0; x < this.state.sidebarItems.length; x++)
        {
            if(this.state.sidebarItems[x].open = true)
            {
                openNumber = x;
            }
            this.state.sidebarItems[x].open = false;
        }

        this.state.sidebarItems[openNumber].open = true;
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div onClick={this.handleItems}>
                {this.state.sidebarItems}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SideBarItemList;
```

Script below of `<SideBarConatiners />` added to hopefully clarify

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import classes from "../../layout/Sidebar.module.css"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class SidebarOption extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: false,
            
        }
    }

    setOpen = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                open: !prevState.open
            }
        })
    }

    setStates = () => {
        this.setOpen()
    }



    render(){
        return (
        <div>
            <Link to={this.props.link}>
                <button
                className={this.state.open ? classes.dropdownbtnopen: classes.dropdownbtn} 
                onClick={this.setStates}>{this.props.name}
                </button>
            </Link>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SidebarOption;
```

Comment: When you say the clicked item is highlighted could it be that just applying a css class to the selected item could solve this? or do you really need to change the state of the item?

Comment: I already have that. The problem is that i want only one item to be highlighted when its been pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add or override prop values for children with `cloneElement(element, props)` [doc](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement).

You would need to change your implementation of `SideBarItemList` to track in local state which child element is selected, and whenever the state changes you would re-render and provide `isSelected: true` to the one selected child element and `isSelected: false` (or nothing) to all others.

An alternative (I don't recommend here) is to implement all children in such a way as to offer an imperative interface (via `forwardRef` and `useImperativeHandle`) that would allow a method call like `child_37.collapse()` and `child_03.expand()`.

Your implementation could look like this:

```
export const SideBarItemList = ({ children }) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState();

  return (
    <ul>
    {
      React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => (
        <li onClick={() => setSelected(index)}>
          {React.cloneElement(child, { isOpen: index === selected })}
        </li>
      ))
    }
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Comment: im having a little bit of a hard time fully understanding what you mean. If you could give me an example that would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: the issue with this solution is that all of my children are different, the props are not the same on every child. And soo im pretty sure i cant use map

Comment: Then rename the _isOpen_ / _isShown_ props so that they all use the same prop name _isOpen_?

Comment: maybe i dont fully understand map but the issue is not the ```isOpen``` variable, the issue is that the childrens props for example the ```options``` prop has a different size and different strings in every child

Comment: `React.cloneElement(child, { isOpen: index === selected })` does only add or override `isOpen`, all other props remains as they are.

Comment: thanks i see that now, and i have implemented your method in my script, the issue im having now is that the index variable is always one step behind the clicked element and im unsure how the isOpen comes into play in my children because right now its just doing the exact same as before

Comment: do you still handle click inside of your child elements? your child elements should only obey the _isOpen_ prop they receive.

Comment: i did do that yes, but now i changed it too only obey the prop and now its working thanks alot for the help man, i guess the open state is useless now in my children class tho. Is using the cloneElement a good way to do this? i read online that its uncommon and can lead to fragile code

Comment: You could restructure your code to get rid of cloneElement. You would need to move the declaration of the items into the ItemList component, so it would be able to just set the property the normal way. Currently the itemlist component can only add properties via cloneElement because the children are declared outside and then given into the itemlist as a prop.